# Print Keys of nested dictionaries in sorted order in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am learning a bit of Python at the moment. One of the first tasks I face is to print the keys of a dictionary and its possible nested dictionaries in sorted order.

The task definition is:

> Write a program to display all the keys of a 'dictionary of dictionaries' (nested dictionary) in sorted order

So I have something like

```
vDict={1:2942, 5:{20:231, 49:359, 65:429}, 39:{9359:2932, 9298:29328, 124:4}}
```

and need to print all of its keys in sorted order.
Theoretically, I am not aware of modules so I can only use built in functions

In my mind, the only way I can come up with is to use the output of `vDict.keys()` function and split with regex in order to sort the values. But then I have no idea how to iterate through tier 2 dictionaries.

I am pretty sure that is not what I am supposed to do here and there is an easier way. I would be interested to see how an educated mind approaches this.

This is a self study during calm work hours so you are not doing my homework here ;)

Comment: Hint: define a recursive function that collects keys from both a given `dict` and any `dict` object used as a value.

Comment: regex is never the answer, only ever a last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def process(dd, keys):

    for key, val in dd.items():
        keys.append(key)
        if isinstance(val,dict):
            process(val, keys)

    return keys


vDict={1:2942, 5:{20:231, 49:359, 65:429}, 39:{9359:2932, 9298:29328, 124:4}}

keys=[]
process(vDict, keys)
print(sorted(keys))
```

Comment: Thanks. I marked yours because it is the most simple approach in my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

The oneliner approach

```
>>> sorted([k for v in vDict.values() if isinstance(v, dict) for k in v] + list(vDict))
[1, 5, 20, 39, 49, 65, 124, 9298, 9359]
```

The split out, slightly more readable version

```
>>> def iterate_keys(d):
...     for k, v in d.items():
...         yield k
...         if isinstance(v, dict):
...             yield from v
...
>>> sorted(iterate_keys(vDict))
[1, 5, 20, 39, 49, 65, 124, 9298, 9359]
```

If you wanted to handle dictionaries with deeper nesting, you could change the `yield from v` line to `yield from iterate_keys(v)` to visit all levels of nesting.

Comment: @kederrac, did you read the comment? No point making it more complicated than the task requires.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
vDict={1:2942, 5:{20:231, 49:359, 65:429}, 39:{9359:2932, 9298:29328, 124:4}}
def get_keys(vDict):
    keys_list = []

    for k in vDict.keys():
        keys_list.append(k)
        if(type(vDict[k]) is dict):
            keys_list = keys_list + get_keys(vDict[k])
    return keys_list
new_list = get_keys(vDict)
new_list.sort()
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 20, 39, 49, 65, 124, 9298, 9359]
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes very much sense to just iterate through the key values of the dictionaries but I did not come up with the idea that this is possible , because the output of vDict.keys() is not clean.

Comment: @Laghorn, you can iterate over the dictionary directly without using `.keys()`. In this example, `for k in vDict:` would work.